# Why Optimizer Does Not Use Index Seek on Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, indexing, sql-server-2014

I wonder why the following `SELECT` statement (below) does not use Index Seek, but Index Scan. Is it just because the number of rows is too small or am I missing something?

**Test data:**

```
-- Init Tables

IF OBJECT_ID ( 'tempdb..#wat' ) IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #wat;

IF OBJECT_ID ( 'tempdb..#jam' ) IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #jam;

CREATE TABLE #wat (
ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
Name VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
Den DATETIME NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE #jam (
ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
Name VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL
)

-- Populate Temp Tables with Random Data

DECLARE @length INT
       ,@charpool VARCHAR(255)
       ,@poolLength INT
       ,@RandomString VARCHAR(255)
       ,@LoopCount INT

SET @Length = RAND() * 5 + 8
SET @CharPool = 'abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ23456789'
SET @PoolLength = LEN(@CharPool)
SET @LoopCount = 0
SET @RandomString = ''

WHILE (@LoopCount < 500) 
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO #jam (Name)
    SELECT    SUBSTRING(@Charpool, CONVERT(int, RAND() * @PoolLength), 5)
    SET @LoopCount = @LoopCount + 1

END

-- Insert Rows into Second Temp Table
INSERT INTO #wat( Name, Den )
SELECT TOP 50 Name, GETDATE()
FROM #jam

-- Create Indexes

--DROP INDEX IX_jedna ON #jam
--DROP INDEX IX_dva ON #wat
CREATE INDEX IX_jedna ON #jam (Name) INCLUDE (ID);
CREATE INDEX IX_dva ON #wat (Name) INCLUDE (ID, Den);

-- Select

SELECT *
FROM #jam j
JOIN #wat w
ON w.Name = j.Name
```

Execution Plan:

[image]

Comment: It's going to look at the histograms for this data and decide what's going to be fastest. It's quite possible that your data is small so a scan is fine. It could, however, be out of date statistics or a missing index.

Comment: I ran your code and I got an index seek. The estimated number of rows on the seek was 12. I ran the code repeatedly and got a seek every time with the estimated number of rows between 10 and 15.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you running?

Comment: Yes, tables are small and there is nothing to `seek`. No filter, and you logically need to _"find matches of all #jam to all #wat"_. Where should `seek` be placed here?

Comment: @IvanStarostin the inner join is performing a filter. #wat has 50 rows which will match a random number of rows in #jam.

Comment: I've tried it on

SQL Server 2012 - Laptop
SQL Server 2014 - Server
SQL Server 2008 R2 - Server

and I get a seek every time.

Comment: I am running SQL Server 2014. I think the scan may be caused also because of the HW of the machine as it is pretty fast one. It is interesting majority here got seek. I am still confused why is that.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways for optimiser to do jons: `nested loops, hash match or merge join` (your case) and may be another. 
In dependence of your data: count of rows, existed indexes and statistics id decides which one is better.

in your example optimiser assumes that there is many-to-many relation. And you have both tables soret(indexed) by this fields.

why merge join? - it is logically - to move through both tables parallel. And server will have to do that only once.

To make `seek` as you want,  the server have to move thorugh first table once, and have to make seeks in second table a lot of times, since all records have matches in another table. Server will read all records if he seeks. And there no profit when using seek (1000 seeks even more difucult than one simple loop through 1000 records).

if you want `seek` add some records with no matches and `where` clause in your query.

**UPD**

even adding simple

```
where j.ID = 1
```

gives you `seek`